# Wordpress Latex и кирилица

Tags: wordpress, плагин, кириллица, latex

Во время работы с Wordpress встретился с проблемой: При использовании плагина  WP Latex появляется ошибка типа "Formula does not parse" при использовании любых символов кириллицы. Можно ли как-то включить алфавит кириллицы в базы плагина?

Comment: очень общий вопрос.

Comment: вероятно, стоит обратиться к разработчиками плагина. или самому стать разработчиком, решив данную проблему.

Comment: Изначально LaTeX кириллические символы он не распознаёт и верстать их не умеет.